# Excel date convert from Mar-29 to 29/03/2020

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

Simple question that I have not been able to find an answer to.

I have some data that doesn't have years and is formatted as Mar-29, as I have pasted into Excel, but Excel converts this into data like this `1/3/2029`.

How can I make this into a usable date format, making all dates for 2020?

Output should be DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: Is a date from the first nine days of the month formatted as Mar-01 or Mar-1?

Comment: (1) What locale are you in?  I.e., what country/language, and how are dates formatted by default? (2) What happens if you manually type “Mar-29” into a cell?  (3) What happens if you enter “Mar-32”?

Comment: earlier dates are Mar-01. locale is british. the same thing happens if I type Mar-29 i.e. "1/3/2029" Mar-32 results in "1/3/1932"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the column that receives the pasted 'dates' as Text *before* pasting the information in. This will allow them to retain the `Mar-29` as text.

Once the text-that-looks-like-a-date values have been pasted in, select the column and run Data, Data Tools, Text to Columns. On the third Text to Columns dialogue page use Date, MDY and click Finish. This will add *2020* as the year for each of the dates.

While the column is still selected, apply the desired date format (Ctrl+1).

If you want to rework the dates after they have been erroneously pasted in then try this formula,

```
=DATE(2020, MONTH(A2), TEXT(A2,"yy"))
```

Comment: I don’t know whether this is right — I can’t test it, because I can’t reproduce the problem — but I believe that ***all*** the others are wrong.

Comment: I think you are on the right track since you at least understood the problem of excel mangling the dates. I tried to format the whole sheet as text before pasting the table (copied from a website) but it did not help. The dates are still mangled upon pasting.

Comment: FWIW, I was able to reproduce the paste problem and this worked on my end. If your problem of pasting no longer produces the `1/3/2029` dates then perhaps just remember this for next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:
`=TEXT(DATEVALUE("29/03/2020"),"dd/mm/yyyy")`

Comment: Where do you get ``01/03/2020``?  You may need to read the question again, more carefully.

Comment: I didn't think something this obvious would need to be explicitly declared, but you should change the date value to whatever date you are trying to output; my answer was mostly intended to provide a purely formulaec methodology, which has advantages in speed-/ease-of-input, etc.  But just to humor you, I've edited in OP's given date, so now it's copy-paste-ready.

Comment: Also, note that despite the misleading formula name (as well as Microsoft help resource), the `=TEXT()` formula does **not** convert the cell data format to `text` string.  Those of you who assumed this should test it for yourselves.

Comment: (1) So you’re saying, if the OP has damaged dates in `A1:A100`, they should type your formula into ***each cell*** `B1`, `B2`, …, `B100`, each time *manually* copying the value displayed in the corresponding cell in Column `A`?  (2) My *point* is that you used an example value that is *similar* to the value in the question, but not the same.  This makes me wonder how carefully you read the question.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Your edit actually made it worse.  I’ll admit, I skimmed your comment before I started to write this comment.  Upon reading your comment carefully (yeah, ironic), I see that you’re saying: ‘‘For each cell, manually determine what value you want it to have, and then type that value.’’

Comment: That's a valid point, and i myself would not do it that way, i would instead point it to a relative column address  so you can copy-paste it down.  i don't know what the literal end-usage will be since there wasn't any screenshot or sample included in the OP, but even then i will say again that my intent was purely to bring to attention that a formulaic method exists.  I'm a bit perplexed as normally when posting Excel questions you catch flack when asking for spoon-fed , PnP solutions, but this is the first time I'm seeing the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,3) &" " & MID(A1,5,2)))
```

and format **B1** as you like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to paste the value into a column formatted as text, then use this formula changing B9 to your target cell:

=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(B9,LEN(B9)-FIND("-",B9,1))&"-"&LEFT(B9,FIND("-",B9,1)-1)&"-2020")

you can then copy and paste the value as a date.

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers so far, except for [Jeeped’s](https://superuser.com/q/1536807/150988#1536819),
seem to assume that you have the *text* “Mar-29” in your spreadsheet. 
If that’s true, then this answer might not be useful to you. 
(Or maybe you can adapt it to your situation.) 
My understanding of the question is:

- You have the *text* “Mar-29” somewhere.
- You paste it into Excel.
- Excel interprets it as `mmm-yy`
  and converts it to the date value Thursday, March 01, 2029, …
- … and displays that value as “1/3/2029” using the `d/m/yyyy` format
  (which is the preferred [numeric date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) in the United Kingdom).
- You want it to be interpreted
  as Sunday, March 29, 2020 (`mmm-dd` + current year)
  and displayed as 29/03/2020 (`DD/MM/YYYY`).

Fixing the pasting process, so you never get wrong data in your spreadsheet
(as [Jeeped’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1536807/150988#1536819) tries to do), may be the best approach. 
But, once you have the 2029, etc., dates in your spreadsheet (say, in `A1`),
you can fix them by putting

```
=DATE(2020, MONTH(A1), YEAR(A1)-2000)
```

into `B1` (or wherever you want). 
This simply builds a date value with

- year=2020,
- month=the month value of the date value in `A1` (March, the 3rd month), and
- day=the year value of the date value in `A1` (2029) minus 2000,
  to get the rightmost two digits.

Of course, if you have more values in Column `A`,
you can drag that formula down Column `B`. 
To apply the fix permanently, copy and paste values. 
I assume that you know how to change the display format for dates.

Notes:

- This may produce bad results if `A1` does not contain
  a date value that’s corrupted in the way you’ve described
  (garbage in, garbage out). 
  You might want to add validation.
- The above formula hard-codes the year 2020. 
  If you want a formula that uses the current year, use

  ```
  =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(A1), YEAR(A1)-2000)
  ```
- I’m not sure why you would want to,
  but you could use `MOD(YEAR(A1), 100)` instead of `YEAR(A1)-2000`
  for the day-of-the-month in `B1`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a formula too.  When the date is in A2, use:

`=CONCATENATE(RIGHT(A2, 2),"-",LEFT(A2,3),"-","2020")`

This assumes the format is always 2 characters for the day and 3 for the month.  If it's sometimes 1 character for the day, you could use MID to look part way into the string, instead of RIGHT.

Comment: no, date should be stored as date, not as text. The output format would be set as desired in the properties

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in DATEVALUE and you're getting close to a solution.